# How can I append lists to a list efficiently?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe, append, nltk

I tried to append `filtered_sentence` to the list `wiki_train_lst`. I found that the step of removing `stop_words` is fast, but removing `common_name` is very slow (maybe there are too many words in `common_name`). How can I quickly filter out both `stop_words` and `common_name`? In addition, the total content to be appended to `wiki_train_lst` is about 416,000 items, which makes the append process very slow: how can I optimize it?

```py
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

wiki_train_lst = []

for text in wiki_train_df.original_text:

    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    tokenizer = tokenizer.tokenize(text)

    #print(word_tokens)

    filtered_sentence = [w.lower() for w in tokenizer if not w.lower() in stop_words] #remove stop words

    #filtered_sentence = [w for w in filtered_sentence if not w in common_surname_lst or not w in common_name_lst]

    filtered_sentence = [w for w in filtered_sentence if not w in common_name_lst] #remove common names

    filtered_sentence = [w for w in filtered_sentence if w.isalpha()] #remove non alphabatics words
    
    wiki_train_lst.append(filtered_sentence)

    #print(filtered_sentence)

wiki_train_lst
```

Comment: Does it help if you move from using list comprehensions to generators? That is, swap your `[... for ... in ... if... ]` for `(... for ... in ... if...)`? This will delay the computation until you reify it.

Comment: one possible optimization is to use set instead of list, because set have a faster membership testing

Answer (score 3):

One way to make it faster is to roll all the list expressions into one:

```py
def my_filter(w):
    w_lower = w.lower()
    if w_lower in stop_words:
        return False
    if w_lower in common_surname_lst 
        return False
    if w_lower in common_name_lst:
        return False
    if not w.isalpha()
        return False
    return True

filtered_sentence = [w.lower() for w in tokenizer if my_filter(w)]

wiki_train_lst.append(filtered_sentence)
```

Note that this adds the overhead of a function lookup, you could re-write the function as a bunch of `and` statements:

```py
filtered_sentence = [w for w in tokenizer if w.lower() not in stop_words 
                                              and w.lower() not in common_surname_lst 
                                              and w.lower() not in common_name_lst 
                                              and w.isalpha()]
```

Now we have a bunch of `w.lowers()`, let's do something about that:  We can use a Generator Expression, which is like a list comprehension, but lazy:

```py
filtered_sentence = [w for w in (w.lower() for w in tokenizer) if w not in stop_words 
                                                                   and w not in common_surname_lst 
                                                                   and w not in common_name_lst 
                                                                   and w.isalpha()]
```

Even better might be to use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```py
filtered_sentence = filter(tokenizer, my_filter)
```

To improve the speed of the `common_name` search, first convert the list to a `set` in one of the above approaches:

```py
common_name_lst = set(common_name_lst)
```

The rest of the code can remain the same, unless you want to rename variables to make the types clearer.

Ultimately, if you need performance, CPython is generally a sub-optimal choice.  There are ways to make it faster (see [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/) or [Cython](https://cython.org/)), but you might be better off re-writing your code in an easier to optimize language.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's a great help!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from itertools import chain

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')

filter_words = set(chain(stop_words, common_name_lst,  common_surname_lst)

def tokenize_text(txt):  # Returns a generator
    tokenized = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    return (w.lower() for w in tokenized if filter_word(w))

def filter_word(word: str) -> bool:  
    w = word.lower()
    return (w not in filter_words and w.isalpha())

training_list = list(chain.fromiterable((tokenize_text(t) for t in wiki_train_df.original_text))
```

This takes advantage of several improvements (though I haven't tested it so there might be a bug or two):

- Do each text as a generator instead of its own list. This means values are calculated just as they're added to the final list, saving memory allocation time. Uses the `itertools` `chain()` function to flatten the list.
- Pre-calculate a set of all the words you want to filter out. A lookup of a value in a set is O(1), versus in a list where it is O(n) - the lookup for a list iterates through each value until it finds the value or exhausts the list. A set is backed by a hash table, though, so this pre-calculation saves time on each iteration.

Comment: You should be able to use `key in dictionary` for O(1) lookup, which avoids a method lookup for `get`, if we're being fussy about performance.

Comment: why dict and not a set?

Comment: also, given that you imported chain, why not use it too to create the dict? and that way not  create unnecessary throw away new lists

Comment: I note that you can also use a set. Most cases I've used this, storing a bool at the key isn't what I'm doing, but storing something more complicated to make the decision from. That said, this case really only requires a set.

Comment: @Copperfield I've updated the result, though I think the key takeaway is that a little precomputation - however you do it - is the key. Optimizing the precomputation is liable to yield lower returns. Nevertheless, I've reduced the response to just using a set for this.

Comment: by  `my_filter` in `tokenize_text` I imagine you mean `filter_word` you defined bellow